# Install 32 bit JVM on mac os 10.10.5

Tags: java, macos, jvm

I am facing issue to install 32 JVM on mac osx 10.10.5. When i run the command java -version -d32. It shows me this error.

> Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
>   Please install the desired version.

How can i resolve this error and install 32 JVM on my machine.

I have checked the Java official websites but i have not found the jdk version 32 bit version. Can anybody point me to the documentation. Also, i have searched the net but have not found any direct answer.

Comment: Honestly: why ?

Comment: @luk2302, if you have any links for 32 JVM would be really helpful. Most of it point to the 64 bit JVM.

Comment: What do you need this for? There is no official 32 bit JDK for recent versions of Mac OS. Try to get a version of your software that works with 64 bit JDK.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have HUGE problem here. Oracle provides JDK in 64bit flavor only. You can always try to install JVM from Apple (1.6). As far as I recall, it was supporting 32/64 bit (to be checked):

https://download.developer.apple.com/Java/java_for_mac_os_x_10.6_update_3_developer_package/javadeveloper_10.6_10m3326.dmg

Another thing you can do is to look for OpenJDK binary with 32bit support:

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/BSDPort/Main